# Create Safari Push Notification signature with Node.js

Tags: node.js, apple-push-notifications, pkcs#7, safari-push-notifications

I am trying to implement Safari Push Notifications as described [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/NotificationProgrammingGuideForWebsites/PushNotifications/PushNotifications.html) in Node.js to run in a Google Cloud Function.

I am trying to use [forge](https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge) to create the detached PKCS#7 signature, but I always get a `"Signature verification of push package failed"` error on my logging endpoint.  I have tried encoding the `signature` in both DER and PEM formats with no success. Based on Apple's PHP example, they want DER.  I have also tried using the `safari push notifications` [package](https://github.com/MySiteApp/node-safari-push-notifications) with no success.

Here is the code:

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
import fs from "fs";
import path from "path";
import express from "express";
import crypto from "crypto";
import forge from "node-forge";
import archiver from "archiver";

const app = express();

const iconFiles = [
    "icon_16x16.png",
    "icon_16x16@2x.png",
    "icon_32x32.png",
    "icon_32x32@2x.png",
    "icon_128x128.png",
    "icon_128x128@2x.png",
];

const websiteJson = {
    websiteName: "...",
    websitePushID: "web.<...>",
    allowedDomains: ["..."],
    urlFormatString: "...",
    authenticationToken: "...",
    webServiceURL: "...",
};

const p12Asn1 = forge.asn1.fromDer(fs.readFileSync("./certs/apple_push.p12", 'binary'));
const p12 = forge.pkcs12.pkcs12FromAsn1(p12Asn1, functions.config().safari.keypassword);

const certBags = p12.getBags({bagType: forge.pki.oids.certBag});
const certBag = certBags[forge.pki.oids.certBag];
const cert = certBag[0].cert;

const keyBags = p12.getBags({bagType: forge.pki.oids.pkcs8ShroudedKeyBag});
const keyBag = keyBags[forge.pki.oids.pkcs8ShroudedKeyBag];
const key = keyBag[0].key;

const intermediate = forge.pki.certificateFromPem(fs.readFileSync("./certs/intermediate.pem", "utf8"));

app.post("/:version/pushPackages/:websitePushId", async (req, res) => {
    if (!cert) {
        console.log("cert is null");

        res.sendStatus(500);
        return;
    }

    if (!key) {
        console.log("key is null");

        res.sendStatus(500);
        return;
    }

    const iconSourceDir = "...";

    res.attachment("pushpackage.zip");

    const archive = archiver("zip");

    archive.on("error", function (err) {
        res.status(500).send({ error: err.message });
        return;
    });

    archive.on("warning", function (err) {
        if (err.code === "ENOENT") {
            console.log(`Archive warning ${err}`);
        } else {
            throw err;
        }
    });

    archive.on("end", function () {
        console.log("Archive wrote %d bytes", archive.pointer());
    });

    archive.pipe(res);

    archive.directory(iconSourceDir, "icon.iconset");

    const manifest: {
        [key: string]: { hashType: string; hashValue: string };
    } = {};

    const readPromises: Promise<void>[] = [];

    iconFiles.forEach((i) =>
        readPromises.push(
            new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                const hash = crypto.createHash("sha512");
                const readStream = fs.createReadStream(
                    path.join(iconSourceDir, i),
                    { encoding: "utf8" }
                );

                readStream.on("data", (chunk) => {
                    hash.update(chunk);
                });

                readStream.on("end", () => {
                    const digest = hash.digest("hex");
                    manifest[`icon.iconset/${i}`] = {
                        hashType: "sha512",
                        hashValue: `${digest}`,
                    };
                    resolve();
                });

                readStream.on("error", (err) => {
                    console.log(`Error on readStream for ${i}; ${err}`);
                    reject();
                });
            })
        )
    );

    try {
        await Promise.all(readPromises);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(`Error writing files; ${error}`);

        res.sendStatus(500);
        return;
    }

    const webJSON = {
        ...websiteJson,
        ...{ authenticationToken: "..." },
    };
    const webHash = crypto.createHash("sha512");

    const webJSONString = JSON.stringify(webJSON);

    webHash.update(webJSONString);

    manifest["website.json"] = {
        hashType: "sha512",
        hashValue: `${webHash.digest("hex")}`,
    };

    const manifestJSONString = JSON.stringify(manifest);

    archive.append(webJSONString, { name: "website.json" });
    archive.append(manifestJSONString, { name: "manifest.json" });

    const p7 = forge.pkcs7.createSignedData();
    p7.content = forge.util.createBuffer(manifestJSONString, "utf8");
    p7.addCertificate(cert);
    p7.addCertificate(intermediate);
    p7.addSigner({
        // @ts-ignore
        key,
        certificate: cert,
        digestAlgorithm: forge.pki.oids.sha256,
        authenticatedAttributes: [{
            type: forge.pki.oids.contentType,
            value: forge.pki.oids.data
          }, {
            type: forge.pki.oids.messageDigest
          }, {
            type: forge.pki.oids.signingTime,
            value: new Date().toString()
          }]
    });
    p7.sign({ detached: true });

    const pem = forge.pkcs7.messageToPem(p7);
    archive.append(Buffer.from(pem, 'binary'), { name: "signature" });

    // Have also tried this:
    // archive.append(forge.asn1.toDer(p7.toAsn1()).getBytes(), { name: "signature" });

    try {
        await archive.finalize();
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(`Error on archive.finalize(); ${error}`);

        res.sendStatus(500);
        return;
    }
});
```

When I download and unzip my package, I run the following command:

```
openssl smime -verify -in signature -content manifest.json -inform der -noverify
```

And it returns: `Verification successful`

Any suggestions on where I am going wrong?

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem... Did you eventually find a solution?

Comment: Sadly, no. I’m still stuck.

Comment: Somehow I just made it work. Just posted it on an answer, hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

After testing everything, using the same approach to signing, I did it. No more `"Signature verification of push package failed"`.

Since I was also getting a "Valid Signature" when checking locally, I started looking elsewhere for the root cause (instead of focusing on the node-forge code).

Some things I think it mattered (I tried after making a bunch of changes, so I'm not sure which one is the solution):

**1. First, check the Web Push Id.**
Make sure the `websitePushID` on your `website.json` matches the exact one you typed when creating your `Web Push Certificate` at Apple for the signature creation. I was grabbing it from the REST request made from the web itself, and I totally forgot that, so on the call from the web I was using a different variation than the one used for the certificate. (double check the javacript code below):

```
window.safari.pushNotification.requestPermission(
            'https://...',
            WEB_PUSH_ID,  <--- THIS must match p12 cert web id. The Website Push ID.
            {},
            checkRemotePermission         // The callback function.
        );
```

Also, the `website.json` itself:

```
const websiteJson = { 
    websiteName: "...",
    websitePushID: WEB_PUSH_ID, // <--- THIS must match p12 cert web id. The Website Push ID.
    allowedDomains: ["..."],
    urlFormatString: "...",
    authenticationToken: "...",
    webServiceURL: "...",
};
```

**2. Place proper icon assets**
Probably not the cause, but for testing purposes, I was using the same icon, renamed 6 times, without scaling. I just created proper assets for each size.

**3. Finally, the snippet I use for signature generation**
Just in case. (Note that I removed all the extra ``, but that might not be it, because I was getting same results before.

```
function signature(manifestData, certOrCertPem, privateKeyAssociatedWithCert)
{
    //A. load the WWWDC cert, always the same
    var intermediateBinnary = fs.readFileSync(Path.resolve('.') + '/AppleWWDRCA.pem', 'utf8')
    //console.log('pem wwwdc ', intermediateBinnary);
    //B. continue signing
    var p7 = forge.pkcs7.createSignedData();
    p7.content = forge.util.createBuffer(manifestData, 'utf8');
    p7.addCertificate(certOrCertPem);
    p7.addSigner({
        key: privateKeyAssociatedWithCert,
        certificate: certOrCertPem,
        digestAlgorithm: forge.pki.oids.sha256
    });
    p7.addCertificate(intermediateBinnary);
    p7.sign({detached: true});
    //console.log('p7: ',p7)

    var pem = forge.pkcs7.messageToPem(p7);
    console.log('pem: ',pem)

    // var lines = pem.split('\n')
    // console.log('lines ',lines);

    // We need to turn into DER according to Apple (sure there are better ways tho)
    var preDer = pem.replace('-----BEGIN PKCS7-----\r\n','');
    preDer = preDer.replace('\r\n-----END PKCS7-----','');
    //console.log('-+pem: ',preDer)

    // var lines = preDer.split('\n')
    // console.log('lines ',lines);

    return preDer;
}


// I call this signature method from:
...

var contentSignature = signature(contentManifestString, certPem, privatePem);
var bufferFromPem = Buffer.from(contentSignature, 'base64'); 
...
// Just add the bufferFromPem to a file
```

**4. Just one more thing.**
Probably not related, since you seem to be extracting bags, cert and keys without problems; but since I struggled, getting empty and undefined ones, I'll leave here how I did it

```
    // Prepare
    var p12 = fs.readFileSync(Path.resolve('.') + '/Cert.p12', 'binary');
    var p12Asn1 = forge.asn1.fromDer(p12, false);
    var p12Parsed = forge.pkcs12.pkcs12FromAsn1(p12Asn1, false, 'HERE_PASSWORD'); 

    // extract bags: https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge/issues/533
    const keyData = p12Parsed.getBags({ bagType: forge.pki.oids.pkcs8ShroudedKeyBag })[forge.pki.oids.pkcs8ShroudedKeyBag]
                    .concat(p12Parsed.getBags({ bagType: forge.pki.oids.keyBag })[forge.pki.oids.keyBag]);
    const certBags = p12Parsed.getBags({ bagType: forge.pki.oids.certBag })[forge.pki.oids.certBag];
    
    // convert a Forge private key to an ASN.1 RSAPrivateKey
    var rsaPrivateKey = forge.pki.privateKeyToAsn1(keyData[0].key);
    // wrap an RSAPrivateKey ASN.1 object in a PKCS#8 ASN.1 PrivateKeyInfo
    var privateKeyInfo = forge.pki.wrapRsaPrivateKey(rsaPrivateKey);
    // convert a PKCS#8 ASN.1 PrivateKeyInfo to PEM
    var privatePem = forge.pki.privateKeyInfoToPem(privateKeyInfo); // <- KEY
    // Get cert as well (pem)
    var certPem = forge.pki.certificateToPem(certBags[0].cert); // <- CERT
```